# Save to same location in Photos app

Tags: windows-10, photos

In Windows 8, I was able to crop pictures easily with the Photo app, and then I could choose to either replace the original picture, or to save a copy. If I saved a copy, it saved it to the same location as the original picture, and added a (2) after it.

In Windows 10, I found a save a copy button, but it saves it to Pictures/Saved Pictures.

How can I get it to save to some other location, or even better back to the original Windows 8 functionality (which was much more intuitive and useful)?

Comment: Not exactly an answer to my question, but at least I have a workaround that suits my particular needs - I am anyways going through the files in File Explorer (aka Windows Explorer), so I first made a copy of the file, and then right-clicked on it to open in Photos, and then saved in same location.

Comment: Good workaround. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be any setting for save location. There is only Save (which replaces) and Save a copy as you mentioned.